# Note able to sort data in ascending/descending based on key of object in angular /typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I am new to angular and trying to make an COVID 19 app in angular where I have two components, `State` component and `District` component.

State component is listing all state in table and when I click on any state It is loading all district list below that state.

Here is my working link: [working link](https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/COVOID-19).

Reference of my expectation: [expected result link](https://www.covid19india.org/)

I want to sort (toggle) my district data for particular state in ascending or descending order when I click on District column of table but I am not able to sort data in any way. Once I am able to sort in ascending then I can write same for descending.

I am getting **error**:

> core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: districtdata.sort is not a function

Here is data I am getting as Json response for particular state

**data.Json**

```
{
  "Pune": {
    "confirmed": 63,
    "lastupdatedtime": "",
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 0
    }
  },
  "Mumbai": {
    "confirmed": 198,
    "lastupdatedtime": "",
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 0
    }
  },
  "Nagpur": {
    "confirmed": 12,
    "lastupdatedtime": "",
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 0
    }
  },
  "Thane": {
    "confirmed": 10,
    "lastupdatedtime": "",
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 0
    }
  },
  "Ahmadnagar": {
    "confirmed": 19,
    "lastupdatedtime": "",
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**District.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cs.districtdata.subscribe(data=>{
      this.districtdata=data
      console.log(data)
    })

  }

  sortDistrict(districtdata){
    this.isAscendingSort=true;
  const x= districtdata.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
   console.log(x)
  }
```

**District.component.html**

```
<div class="district-heading">
    <th (click)="sortDistrict(districtdata)">
        <div class="heading-content">
            <abbr class="dist" title="District">District</abbr>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="heading-content">
            <abbr class="confirmed" title="Confirmed">Confirmed</abbr>
        </div>
    </th>
</div>
```

Comment: `districtdata` seems to be an *object*, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your districtdata is an object. If you want a orderd list, you'll need to transform it into an array:

```
const districtData = {
/* your district data */
};

let newArr = [];
Object.keys(districtData).forEach((key, index) => {
 newArr.push(districtData[key]);
});
```

sort() is a function on arrays (and beside you can't / should not try to order objects or make assumptions based on their order.

EDIT:
This code includes the stateName in the object and sorts the new array based on it:

```
const districtData = {
  /* your district data */
};

let districtDataArray = [];
Object.keys(districtData).forEach((key, index) => {
  districtDataArray.push(
    Object.assign({}, { districtName: key }, districtData[key])
  );
});

compare = (a, b) => {
  return a.districtName.localeCompare(b.districtName);
};

districtDataArray.sort(compare);
```

Comment: In this my district name is lost 0:
confirmed: 63
lastupdatedtime: ""
delta: {confirmed: 0} I am getting data like this

Comment: I just updated my answer to add the district name to the object.

Comment: Yeah got it.Its working and do I need to proceed same for "confirmed" to sort which is inside district name?

Comment: for sorting based on "confirmed" you would have another comparator. Because it's a number, you could use `return a.confirmed - b.confirmed` inside.

Comment: Thnaks a lot man you solved my great headache I wish I could upvote you more than one time...Thanks a lot both issue solved

Comment: One more thing how should I access that value of object in my template to render bec now it becomes staename and data.statename is giving error in ngFor

Comment: I changed stateName to districtName when I noticed that mistake. Perhaps you took the code before I changed it?

you should be able to map over the array in your table:
`
<tbody>
{
districtDataArray.map((item, index) => {
return(
<tr><span>{item.districtName}</span><span>{item.confirmed}</span></tr>)
})
}
</tbody>

`

That's how I would do it.

Comment: I think you have mentioned solution to render datta in react but I am using angular  and If you have mentioned angular thn I apologize but I didnt get it ,Also before taking code I have changed name statename to districtname and given it to my districtdata which I am looping

Comment: <div *ngFor="let data of districtdata|keyvalue"><td> {{data.key}}</td></div> This is the way I am rendering data or you can check stackblitz link:https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/COVOID-19

Comment: Oh, I got confused as I was answering another question about React code. 
You array is now built like this:
[{districtName: "Mumbai", confirmed: 192}, {}] and you can access elements only with the index: array[0] would return the Mumbai object.

I don't know Angular and I'm not sure what would be the best way to access the values there. array.map() is part of javascript though, this should work in Angular as well?
In any case, you need to iterate over the array somehow.